# How to open a port in macOS Sierra 10.12.4

Tags: macos, firewall

I'm running macOS Sierra 10.12.4 and am trying to open a port (12345). I can't use the GUI firewall tool as it's app specific, not port specific.

I have tried the following [this article](https://gauravsohoni.wordpress.com/2015/04/14/mac-osx-open-port/), but it did not work. When I run `sudo pfctl -f /etc/pf.conf` I get:

```
pfctl: Use of -f option, could result in flushing of rules
present in the main ruleset added by the system at startup.
See /etc/pf.conf for further details.

No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
```

It may also help to note that in my firewall (GUI) options I have blocked pretty much all options as shown below.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

The linked How-to is wrong!

You simply can't **open** a port in a firewall. You can block a port or not. By default pf is disabled and doesn't block anything. If you enable stealth mode in the Application Firewall, pf will be enabled via the com.apple/250.ApplicationFirewall anchor with a very limited set of rules:

```
scrub in all fragment reassemble
block drop in inet proto icmp all icmp-type echoreq
block drop in inet proto icmp all icmp-type echoreq
block drop in inet6 proto ipv6-icmp all icmp6-type echoreq
```

Except incoming IPv4/6 ICMP echo request, pf won't block anything. The default pf.conf doesn't contain any `block all ...` or `allow all ...` rules.

To open a port on your host, you have to **launch an app which opens a listening port**. Example nc:

```
nc -l 12345
```

After entering the command you will be asked to accept incoming network connections for nc by the Application Firewall.

To connect to nc listening at port 12345 from remote simply enter `nc hostname 12345` on a second host (replace *hostname* with the host name of the Mac running *nc*).

You can check open ports from remote by entering `nmap hostname -Pn` (if stealth mode is enabled).

Comment: I think it's quite commonly understood that by "open a port in the firewall", people typically mean "unblock a port".

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the firewall first.  In *System Preferences* >> *Security and Privacy* under the *Firewall* tab, tick the box to enable it (you will have to unlock first).

[image]

Alternativily, you can do this via Terminal:

```
$ sudo pfctl -E
```

Once you enable the firewall, you shouldn't get the `No ALTQ support in kernel` error message.

Comment: "No ALTQ" is a limitation of the kernel. You will **always** get this message in macOS after enabling pf. The application firewall of the OP is already enabled or he wouldn't be able to see the firewall options.

Comment: @klanomath - Did this change for Sierra?  This is how I fixed this issue once before....